# Inserting Data into a table using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data using a subquery. I am only going to post my `SELECT` statement below.

```sql
SELECT PlaylistCode
FROM Playlists
WHERE Name_Of_Playlist = 'X'
AND 
(SELECT Code
  FROM Songs
  INNER JOIN Artists ON Artists.PageURL = Songs.PageURL
  WHERE Artist = 'X'
  LIMIT 200)
```

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row 0.016 sec

Comment: In addition to missing `EXISTS`, your query is also missing aliases, which would have helped someone correct your syntax much faster.

Comment: @JS . . . You should explain what you want the code to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Here is my Partial EERD: [EERD](https://i.imgur.com/VJdr3Lq.png) Here is my list SongCode where Artist = ‘X’: [Artist X](https://i.imgur.com/uJb2JVh.png)

Comment: @GordonLinoff In Songs Table PageURL is a PK. In Artists Table, PageURL is a Foreign Key referencing Songs.PageURL. In Playlists table, SongCode is FK referencing Songs.Code. In PlaylistSongs table, PlaylistCode is referencing Playlists.PlaylistCode. In Playlists table, UserCode is referencing Auth_User.UserCode. I want to insert all Songs from Songs table to PlaylistSongs table where artist = 'X' to PlaylistSongs table where Name_of_Playlist = ‘Y’. I hope you can understand it now.

Comment: Better version of EERD [Link](https://i.imgur.com/TED54M8.png)

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1):

Try to Below Query

```
SELECT PlaylistCode
FROM Playlists
WHERE exits 
(SELECT Code
  FROM Songs
  INNER JOIN Artists ON Artists.PageURL = Songs.PageURL
  WHERE Artist = 'X'
  LIMIT 200) and Name_Of_Playlist = 'X'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, you need to use `select case` then `join` corresponding tables

```
  INSERT INTO Playlists (PlaylistCode)
    SELECT CASE WHEN a.Artist = 'X' THEN 'X' ELSE s.Code END   
    FROM Songs s
    INNER JOIN Artists a ON a.PageURL = s.PageURL
```

Comment: I tried with exist & its only showing 1 result. My full query:  INSERT INTO PlaylistSongs (PlaylistCode, SongCode)
SELECT Playlists.PlaylistCode
FROM Playlists
WHERE Playlists.Name_Of_Playlist = 'Babbu Maan'
AND EXISTS 
(SELECT Songs.Code
FROM Songs
INNER JOIN Artists ON Artists.PageURL = Songs.PageURL
WHERE Artists.Artist = 'Babbu Maan'
LIMIT 200)

Comment: removed limit 200, try again

Comment: still same issue.

Comment: i need your data and expected output, for us to solve this out

Comment: What I am trying to do is where ever the artist name = 'X' set the PlaylistCode to 'X' and insert all values to table PlaylistSongs

Comment: I want to insert all these to table Playlists with PlaylistCode which lives in Playlists table as a FK. https://i.imgur.com/l8ExTMX.png

Comment: Didn't work. I had to just manually insert it using csv to sql editior which made all my insert queries. I exported all the results I wanted then used online editor to create insert statements.